# Задача о "Золотой горе" (Java)

Tags: java

> На рисунке изображен треугольник из чисел. Вычислить наибольшую сумму
>   чисел, которые встречаются на пути, путь начинается с верхней точки
>   треугольника и заканчивается на его основе. Шаг пути может быть вниз
>   по диагонали влево или вниз по диагонали вправо. Треугольник из целых чисел от 1
>   до 99. Количество строк треугольника выбрать произвольно.

Олимпиадная и уже всем знакомая задачка, вот только у меня не выходит.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mountain
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int [][] a; 
int [][] b; 
int i;
int j;
    System.out.println("Введите количество строк в треугольнике:");
    Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        n= value.nextInt();
        a=new int[n][];
        b=new int[n][];
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            a[i]=new int[n];
            b[i]=new int[n];
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                b[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                Scanner valuefori = new Scanner(System.in);
                Scanner valueforj = new Scanner (System.in);
                int sizei = valuefori.nextInt();
                int sizej = valueforj.nextInt();
                i = sizei;
                j=sizej;
                 a = new int [i][j];
                b[0][0] = a[0][0];
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (b[i + 1][j] < b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j])
                {
                    b[i + 1][j] = b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j];
                }
                if (b[i + 1][j + 1] < b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j + 1])
                {
                    b[i + 1][j + 1] = b[i][j] + a[i + 1][j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
        int max=b[n-1][0];
        for(i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (b[n - 1][i] > max)
            {
                max = b[n - 1][i];
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Максимальная сумма " + max);
}
}
```

Comment: А одним Scanner-ом нельзя было все числа вводить?

Comment: В программе нет ввода массива а.

Comment: Дак как нет).А как же ввод через сканер?

Comment: Вводите только i,j

Comment: a = new int [i][j] - это не ввод числа, а создание нового массива. Вы i*j раз создаете массив! Память расходуется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решается рекурсивным обходом, где результат - это сумма текущего элемента и максимального из правого нижнего и левого нижнего треугольника

Сам треугольник удобно хранить в двумерном массиве с переменной длиной. Тогда будет разрешен спуск на следующую строку только на элемент с таким же индексом или на 1 больше. Т.е. треугольник

```
   1
  2 3
 4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

храним как

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

В итоге получаем

```
int getMaxTrace(int [][] a, int col, int row) {
  int res = a[row][col];
  if (row != a.length - 1) {
    int left = getMaxTrace(a, col, row + 1);
    int right = getMaxTrace(a, col + 1, row + 1);
    res += Math.max(left, right);
  }
  return res;
}

getMaxTrace(a, 0, 0);
```

Заполнение массива `а` реализовать самостоятельно

Comment: Если ввод правильно реализовать, то и бабы-ежкин код сработает, наверное.

Comment: Кхм, зачем тут рекурсия? И да, уже на 35+ строчках это будет работать слишком долго. Или использовать мемоизацию или вообще делать это снизу вверх простейшим ДП.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так реализуете ввод массива

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
             a[i]=new int[i+1];
             b[i]=new int[i+1];
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                 int sizei  = sc.nextInt();
                  a[i][j] = sizei;
                  b[i][j] = 0;

            }
        }
```